# How to read from std vector front and remove read variable?

Tags: c++, stl, std

How to read from std vector front and remove read variable?

Is it:

```
v.front();
v.erase(v.begin());
```

Comment: You didn't exactly do anything with the value you got from it. If this is all you're doing, you might consider something like a stack, though, depending on what else you need to do with it.

Comment: Removing from the front is expensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks about right, but consider switching to a std::deque which has a pop_front function (which won't have to move all the elements in the container)

Comment: is code like `message << v->front(); v->pop_front(); `faster?

Comment: For that single operations, yes, but depending on what else you do with `v` it might still make sense to continue using a `vector`.